# Older movies on Amazon Prime stutter whilst newer movies and all TV series stream fine

Tags: video, amazon, video-streaming, streaming

If I try to watch *Crocodile Dundee* for example I get major stutters (3-5 seconds long every 3-5 seconds) yet it's only older movies. All modern movies play fine as do all TV shows, it's bizarre and a little infuriating.

I have a solid 17mbs internet speed and a decent enough computer, I can't figure out what's causing it or how to resolve it. This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

At this point all signs point to it being a problem on Amazon's end but I've not come across anyone else complaining about the same thing in my search to find a solution.

Any ideas?